# как писать приложения под Android

Tags: java, android, apk

У меня есть два файла:
`Main.java` `Main.class`

Как я могу получить из этого `Main.apk`?

здесь я новичок, использую windows 7.

Можно ли это провернуть без *android studio* ? (комп слабоват)

**Цель**: писать приложения под Android

прошу направить меня

Comment: Андроид приложение требует гораздо больше для сборки, чем только java-код. С выходом AS из SDK убрали возможность генерировать шаблон проекта из командной строки, не вручную же его будете создавать. К сожалению, для новичка это нереально, так что хотите писать -- ставьте AS.

Comment: Структура андроид-приложения кардинальным образом отличается от десктопной Java, чтобы писать приложения под андроид надо учиться отдельно всему практически с нуля. Для старта рекомендую книгу Б. Филлипса "Андроид. Программиррвание для профессионалов" последних изданий (самое последнее по Kotlin вместо Java). Десктопный java-код не будет исполнятся на андроид-устройстве. Собрать приложение без IDE в современных реалиях тоже является нетривиальной задачей.

Answer (score 3):

При желании приложение можно написать через блокнот. Вот пример, если папка приложения (`myApp`) размещается на `Рабочем столе`:

1. В папке `myApp` создаём ещё четыре папки: `bin`, `obj`, `res`, `src`;
2. Здесь же создаём файл `AndroidManifest.xml` вот такого содержания:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    package="com.example.testapp">
    <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

    <application 
    android:label="TestApp">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

3. В папку `res` добавляем папку `values` с файлом `strings.xml` такого содержания:

```
<resources>
    <string name="hello">Hello myApp</string>
</resources>
```

4. Создаём в папке `src` другие папки: `com` => `example` => `testapp`;
5. В папке `testapp` создаём файл `MainActivity.java` такого содержания:

```java
package com.example.testapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setText(getString(R.string.hello));
        setContentView(textView);
    }
}
```

6. В папке `myApp` создаём "сборщик" файл `builder.bat`:

```bat
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Users\Username\Desktop\jdk //обычно отличается :)
set ANDROID_HOME=D:\AndroidStudioSDK //отличается
set DEV_HOME=%CD%

set AAPT_PATH=%ANDROID_HOME%/build-tools/30.0.2/aapt.exe //может отличаться
set DX_PATH=%ANDROID_HOME%/build-tools/30.0.2/dx.bat //может отличаться
set ANDROID_JAR=%ANDROID_HOME%/platforms/android-23/android.jar //также может отличаться
set ADB=%ANDROID_HOME%/platform-tools/adb.exe

set PACKAGE_PATH=com/example/testapp
set PACKAGE=com.example.testapp
set MAIN_CLASS=MainActivity

REM create R.java
call %AAPT_PATH% package -f -m -S %DEV_HOME%/res -J %DEV_HOME%/src -M %DEV_HOME%/AndroidManifest.xml -I %ANDROID_JAR%

REM compiling java classes
call %JAVA_HOME%/bin/javac -d %DEV_HOME%/obj -cp %ANDROID_JAR% -sourcepath %DEV_HOME%/src %DEV_HOME%/src/%PACKAGE_PATH%/*.java

REM converting *.class
call %DX_PATH% --dex --output=%DEV_HOME%/bin/classes.dex %DEV_HOME%/obj

REM packing APK
call %AAPT_PATH% package -f -M %DEV_HOME%/AndroidManifest.xml -S %DEV_HOME%/res -I %ANDROID_JAR% -F %DEV_HOME%/bin/AndroidTest.unsigned.apk %DEV_HOME%/bin

REM signing APK
call %JAVA_HOME%/bin/keytool -genkey -validity 10000 -dname "CN=AndroidDebug, O=Android, C=US" -keystore %DEV_HOME%/AndroidTest.keystore -storepass android -keypass android -alias androiddebugkey -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048
call %JAVA_HOME%/bin/jarsigner -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore %DEV_HOME%/AndroidTest.keystore -storepass android -keypass android -signedjar %DEV_HOME%/bin/AndroidTest.signed.apk %DEV_HOME%/bin/AndroidTest.unsigned.apk androiddebugkey

pause
```

7. Если хочется использовать ADB для установки на устройство (у меня не всегда работало), добавляем в `builder.bat` этот код:

```bat
set ADB=%ANDROID_HOME%/platform-tools/adb.exe

REM using ADB
call %ADB% uninstall %PACKAGE%
call %ADB% install %DEV_HOME%/bin/AndroidTest.signed.apk
call %ADB% shell am start -n %PACKAGE%/%PACKAGE%.%MAIN_CLASS%
```

8. Структура папки `myApp` при выполнении команды `tree C:/Users/Username/Desktop/myApp /F` в `Windows`:

```
C:\USERS\USERNAME\DESKTOP\MYAPP
│   AndroidManifest.xml
│   builder.bat
│
├───bin
├───obj
├───res
│   └───values
│           strings.xml
│
└───src
    └───com
        └───example
            └───testapp
                    MainActivity.java
```

9. После запуска файла `builder.bat` в папке `bin` появится файл `AndroidTest.signed.apk` - приложение, которое можно установить на устройство.

**P.S.** Может стоит попробовать [Eclipse](https://habr.com/ru/post/109944/)?

Comment: А теперь добавляем какие-нибудь библиотеки из jet pack? Как эксперимент это имеет право на существование, но для реальной работы больше похоже на склонность к мазохизму. Eclipse остановился на поддержке андроида в районе 5 версии где то, вместе с окончанием разработки и поддержки плагина ADT и переходом на сборку через gradle, насколько я помню те давние времена, в современной разработке имеет поезность чуть выше блокнота того же :)

Comment: @pavlofff, согласен, Eclipse это не AndroidStudio и подключить jetpack в нём не получится (на сколько понимаю, подключается только *.jar). Я предложил его потому, что человеку нужно было что-то легче студии.